# unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x84b1c20' - How to cast from UIVIEW to UIViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

what's the way that i can resolve it.

```
  NavigationControllerWithSlider* controller = (NavigationControllerWithSlider*) self.ViewLocations;    // ViewLocations ----> subView of ViewController && NavigationControllerWithSlider is a ViewController .


 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setRightSlidingViewWithSliderImage:length:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x805df60'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1bec012 0x1508e7e 0x1c774bd 0x1bdbbbc 0x1bdb94e 0x19f7c 0x90d1c7 0x90d232 0x90d4da 0x9248e5 0x9249cb 0x924c76 0x924d71 0x92589b 0x925e93 0x925a88 0xb9a6 0xb3e8 0xaf40 0x8db285 0x8db4ed 0x44c5b3 0x1bab376 0x1baae06 0x1b92a82 0x1b91f44 0x1b91e1b 0x1b467e3 0x1b46668 0x82bffc 0x86dd 0x22b5)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```

Here is my Code:

```
//ViewController.m

NavigationControllerWithSlider* controller = (NavigationControllerWithSlider*) self.ViewLocations;    // ViewLocations ----> subView of ViewController
    UIImage * img = [UIImage imageNamed: @"open_panel.png"];
    UIImage * closeImg = [UIImage imageNamed: @"close_panel.png"];

    UIImage * img1 = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:img.CGImage scale:img.scale orientation:UIImageOrientationUpMirrored];
    UIImage * closeImg1 = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:closeImg.CGImage scale: closeImg.scale orientation:UIImageOrientationUpMirrored];

    [controller setRightSlidingViewWithSliderImage:img1 length:300.0f];
    controller.rightSlidingViewControllerId = @"toBeEmbeddedRight";
    controller.rightSlidingView.hideSliderImage = closeImg1;
    controller.rightSlidingView.headPadding = 44.0f;
    controller.rightSlidingView.trailPadding = 44.0f;
```

---

```
//NavigationControllerWithSlider.m

- (void) setRightSlidingViewWithSliderImage: (UIImage*) image length: (CGFloat) length {
    _rightSlidingView = [[SlidingViewController alloc] initWithPosition: DDSliderPositionRight image: image length: length];
    _rightSlidingViewControllerId = @"";
}
```

What I'm missing here.. ? Any help plz....

Comment: are u getting a compiler warning?

Comment: problem is that self.ViewLocations returns UIView which doesn't implement your method. Maybe you should use self.navigationController instead (assuming that you are using you custom class NavigationControllerWithSlider as navigation controller of this view controller)

Comment: @Ishank No... only at runtime exception

Comment: @art-divin : Yes, but actually I'm using splitViewController, Its about to be big app . In that for one of my class had a subView , Here I just need to assign a slider(popup from right) so using some custom class i..e. NavigationControllerWithSlider.

Comment: is ViewLocations a retained property? it might be getting released till u call the method..

Comment: @Ishank . Yes , (at)property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *ViewLocations; & synthesised also...

Comment: read my comment to the first answer - you are working with UIView instance, but you want to access NavigationControllerWithSlider instance which is not set properly

Comment: How u setting self.ViewLocations = ?

Comment: @Ishank : I just need to refer My subview as ViewController that is going to achieve a slider for mySubview .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you have to set the instance of your NavigationControllerWithSlider explicitly to client view controller. To do that, you can use this or similar approach:

```
@interface NavigationControllerWithSlider : UINavigationController

// some custom interface
// ..

- (void)setRightSlidingViewWithSliderImage:(UIImage *)image length:(CGFloat)length;

@end

// this is the main controller with strong property of NavigationControllerWithSlider instance
@interface MainRootViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NavigationControllerWithSlider *sliderController;

@end

@implementation MainRootViewController

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _sliderController = [NavigationControllerWithSlider new];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)presentPopup {
    SomeController *newControllerForPopup = [[SomeController alloc] init];
    newControllerForPopup.sliderController = self.slider;

    // present controller and use slider ^ that you've set here explicitly
}

@end

// here is an example of using and declaring of public property
@interface SomeController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) NavigationControllerWithSlider *sliderController;

@end

@implementation SomeController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // do some additional view configuration using self.sliderController
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer , everything is okay , but I didn't get "" @implementation NSObject (SomeCustomCategoryOrSomeOtherPlace) "" . Can you plz elaborate it.

Comment: I've expanded this part of the example to make it more clear

Answer (score 1):

You are casting an object to `NavigationControllerWithSlider`, but my guess is that object is not really a `NavigationControllerWithSlider`. Can you add a log in above calling `setRightSlidingViewWithSliderImage`

```
NSLog(@"Class of controller: %@", NSStringFromClass([controller class]));
```

(or just let us know what `self.ViewLocations` is declared as)

Comment: 1.0[1954:c07] Class of controller: UIView . Yes You are right . wt else I can do here to achieve.

Comment: I'm just trying to add a slider(like pop up) for my subview. so how could i achieve it ...

Comment: you'll have to set explicitly property of type "NavigationControllerWithSlider" to the "client-view controller" - to the place where you want to access this controller. And then you'll gain the access to NavigationControllerWithSlider instance. Right now there's a UIView instance in self.ViewLocations, that's why the exception is thrown

Comment: @art-divin Yes , I got it . but How can I "" set explicitly property of type "NavigationControllerWithSlider" to the "client-view controller" ""

Comment: I will add an answer in a minute